# what is cpu agnostic means

Tags: cil

This may be a basic question, but what is the definition of what CIL means?

I know that CIL is a platform and CPU agnostic intermediate language, but
t would be helpful someone explained some details about this, and what CPU agnostic means.

Comment: @Timothy - Your edit changes the meaning of the question and you should ask the OP to clarify CIL vs. CLI before doing so.

Comment: @Yuck

Noted! thanks for the notification there, but the original post said `CLI`, and i did not change it.
+1 on your answer.

Answer (score 8):

If something is `platform agnostic`, that means it will be no different on different platforms.

(read : it works the same way on different operating systems, and possibly devices)

If something is `CPU agnostic`, that means it will work the same way on different processors

(so it will do the exact same things on, say an ARM processor as it would on, for example an X86 family processor)

Answer (score 1):

CIL is Common Intermediate Language. It's what any .NET language gets compiled into that remains the same across OS and CPU.

See [Common Intermediate Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).